# PostgreSQLAdapter escape result of executing sql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter will do escape result of executing sql? I see what this will escape double quotes in returned result, but i not sure what adapter do this by default.

Example:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter.execute("SELECT * FROM table_name")
```